# Ruby strange result of decimal number division

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I met strange problem. We have a script in our Ruby on Rails app, where the cut off point for some condition is **0.8**.

What seems weird when I tried to divide 2.4 by 3 Ruby gives result **0.799999**.
For test purposes I divided 2.4 by 4 or 6 and the results were 0.6 and 0.4, respectively, so mathematically looks correct for those numbers. Do you have an idea why Ruby calculates **2.4 / 3 = 0.799999** ?

Comment: Floating point rounding errors. If you're handling money try using cents instead of float values, or look at the money gem

Comment: Hint: it's *not* decimal division, it's binary.

Comment: [What every computer scientist should know about Floating Point Arithmetic](https://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/bachelor/IEEE754_article.pdf) is the seminal article on this.  A nicer, more user friendly summary is available at [https://floating-point-gui.de/](https://floating-point-gui.de/)